# Wrong shortest distance BFS algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am doing this problem http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=2915&rd=5853, but my program gives wrong output, I tried more ways and it does not work properly. I do not get it, because other people do it like me and they are fine. Can you please check if I have properly implemented the BFS? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#define P push
#define PP pop();
#define T front();

int mo[][2] = { {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}, {-1, -2}, {1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {1, 2} };
int m[8][8];

int BFS(int sy, int sx, int fy, int fx)
{
    queue<int> s;
    m[sy][sx] = 1;
    s.P(sy);
    s.P(sx);
    s.P(0);
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        int d = s.T s.PP
        int x = s.T s.PP
        int y = s.T s.PP
        for(int i=0;i < 8;i++)
        {
            int yy = y + mo[i][0]; 
            int xx = x + mo[i][1];
            if(yy < 0 || yy > 7 || xx < 0 || xx > 7) continue;
            if(m[yy][xx] != -1) continue;
            if(yy == fy && xx == fx) return d + 1;
            m[yy][xx] = 0;
            s.P(yy);
            s.P(xx);
            s.P(d+1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

class CaptureThemAll {
public:
    int fastKnight(string knight, string rook, string queen) {
        vector<int> p{knight[0] - 'a', knight[1] - '1', rook[0] - 'a', rook[1] - '1', queen[0] - 'a', queen[1] - '1'};
        memset(m, -1, sizeof(m));
        int a = BFS(p[1], p[0], p[3], p[2]);
        memset(m, -1, sizeof(m));
        int b = BFS(p[1], p[0], p[5], p[4]);
        memset(m, -1, sizeof(m));
        int c = BFS(p[3], p[2], p[5], p[4]);
        return min(a,b) + c;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Don't put `;` in macros unless you have a really good reason, and use more meaningful names.

Comment: @Leeor: Agreed on the semicolon part, but the names are just for brevity in a competitive environment were coding time is the key (and nobody is going to read that code after you wrote it). Although in this particular case they are more or less useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you push y,x,d so your queue will be

```
Front y  Middle x End d
```

But when you pop the front element you place it (y) into a variable called d.

It may work better if you change:

```
    int d = s.T s.PP
    int x = s.T s.PP
    int y = s.T s.PP
```

to

```
    int y = s.T s.PP
    int x = s.T s.PP
    int d = s.T s.PP
```

Comment: Thank you, I used stack for DFS first time. Now it works just fine.